# Salesforce Professional Edition Page Layouts

Tags: page-layout, professional-edition

Can we create more than 2 page layouts for any objects in professional edition? The doc says that it's limited to 2 page layouts per object, but it's not and I can create more than 2 page layouts. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

- Can we create more than 2 page layouts for any objects in professional edition?

  **Yes** we can

Salesforce recommends creating **NO** more than 200 page layouts. While there is no limit, organizations may have difficulty managing their page layouts if they exceed 200. I don't know were you found that information but certainly that's not correct.

Page layout plays an important role when dealing with record types on various records. You can assign different page layouts to different record types on a single object.

Comment: You can only create 2 custom profiles and 3 record types per object so there's a limitation there regarding usage of page layouts

Comment: @Christoph I doubt about custom profiles but there is no as such limitation of number of record types. Refer this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=recordtypes_picklists_limitations.htm&type=0&language=en_US)

Comment: Check this out (2nd page, right column, Professional edition): https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/datasheets/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf

Comment: @Christoph and Rohit.. Thanks.. I was looking into the same sheet before and that is where I got confused. It says **Custom Profiles and Page Layouts -2** I'm pretty clear with Custom Profiles (Limited to 2 custom profiles per license type), and what about page layouts?